# proper use of exec command to call wget in unix

Tags: c++, unix, exec, wget

i try to call wget from a c++ program in unix. I want to call it inside a child proccess after using fork, i need to use exec and not system(). what i have done is

```
pid_t pID = fork();
if (pID == 0)
{
   execl("/bin/wget","wget", "http://google.gr",(char*)0);
}
```

and expect to have a html file in the same folder the executable file is, 
but this does not happen, how should i do it properly?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest fully qualifying the path -- not every system your software is installed on will necessarily have wget in `/bin`; sometimes it may be in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc; and the user running your software may have a custom wget that they want to use in their local PATH before these. Just calling it with `"wget"` in the first argument will cause the PATH to be searched, such that the binary will be found wherever it is.

Comment: thanks a lot, actually what i was doing wrong was that the path is /usr/bin/wget but your recommendation to call it with wget in first argument is the proper solution, thanks again

Comment: I added an answer describing using proper error handling -- doing that, your program would emit a "file not found" error in this case, so it would be obvious what the problem was -- and reiterating the contents of the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `/bin/wget` -- `wget` won't always be installed in `/bin`; just passing `wget` alone in the first argument will cause the PATH to be searched.

Second, you shouldn't assume that `execl` doesn't return. Rather, you should call `perror()` to properly log an error (and then, in your code, exit with a nonzero status) after it.

You can also see what's happening using `strace -f` on the parent process and looking for the exec, but adding error-handling to your code is the right thing in any event.